# Firebase admin sdk: query realtime database (timestamp)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to query for data that's more then 8 hours old.

My data is stored like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user 1": {
      "beginTime": 1576754815639,
      //more data
    },
    "user 2": { ... },
    "user 3": { ... }
  }
}
```

I'm using the firebase admin sdk (for use with a cloud function)
I found this example on their website.

```
  var ref = db.ref("dinosaurs");
  ref.orderByChild("height").startAt(3).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
  });
```

But I have no idea if I need "child_added" or how to implement startAt with the time.

How can I query for timestamps that are 8 (or more) hours old?

Thanks in advance for the help and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
  var ref = db.ref("users");
  ref.orderByChild("beginTime").startAt(1576754815639).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
```

Add a reference to node `users` then using `orderByChild` to query and attach a `value` event to the query to retrieve the data

Check the docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: Thanks! If i'm right, the time is now hard coded? Is it possible to make it 'change'. I would like to use the server timestamp and query all data that's more then 8 hours ago then the current timestamp.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.ServerValue

Comment: So if I read the documentation right, i need the 'data' from [ - infinity to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP minus 8 hours]. So i should use endAt (serverValue.Timestamp minus 8 hours)? How can you write ServerValue.TIMESTAMP minus 8 hours in code?